# Using of the word "Mathematician"

Tags: phd, mathematics

Is is true to call a newly Ph.D graduated of mathematics a

> Mathematician ?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In what context?

Comment: When using it in a website  ?

Comment: Anyone who practices mathematics is a mathematician.

Comment: The "title" "mathematician" isn't regulated by anything. If you have a PhD in math, then sure, you are a mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a protected title, so you can call anyone you want a mathematician. More practically, I would call someone who identifies him or herself as a mathematician, a mathematician.